# Add a click event on inline remove tag in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add a click event to the remove tag link in wordpress' inline tag editor on a post edit page using the following code.

```
$j('#my_taxonomy .tagchecklist').on( 'click', 'a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('test');
});
```

It works if I replace 'click' with 'hover' and the tag is being removed as normal. Is there something that would stop the click event from working?

thanks

Comment: i haven't used wordpress ever but have you tried `delegate` instead of `on`.And what is that `$j`, is that related to wordpress? (sorry for asking question in comment :))

Comment: Delegate did the same thing as on (considering this method signature [event delegation way] ) .. Ain't `delegate` deprecated ? `:/`

Comment: j is just for no conflict, forgot to delete it when I pasted the code. On appears to do everything delegate did.

Comment: Did you find any errors in your console ?

Comment: no, nothing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$j('#my_taxonomy .tagchecklist a').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('test');
});
```

If it doesn't work, maybe this would work:

```
$j('body').delegate('#my_taxonomy .tagchecklist a', 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated, `on` is  for delegated event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it with this.

```
 $j(document).on('click', "a.ntdelbutton", function(event){

 alert('test');

 });
```